# Dataflow job unable to write to BigQuery dataset in different region even if zone is set to the region of bigquery dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are writing a Dataflow job to write data from `JSON` in storage bucket to BigQuery dataset. Both storage bucket and BigQuery dataset are in region `X`. However, dataflow endpoint is not available in region `X`. The nearest region is `Y`. So, I have set Dataflow job region as `Y`, but zone as `X`. So, all the compute instances are getting spun up in region `X`. However, still Dataflow job fails with the error:

> Cannot read and write in different locations: source: Y, destination: X

Both temp location and staging location storage buckets are set to region x.

The beam version used is `2.17` and SDK is `Python SDK`.

We are creating a dataflow-template and running it (DataflowRunner). The template is also in region `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Staging buckets for Dataflow jobs needs to be multi-regional or at least be in the same region than the BigQery datasets they're writing to. You could work around this problem by hosting the data in the same location as the Dataflow job is running.

Please note that when reading or [writing to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#data-locations), Google Cloud Storage bucket is used for staging files, based on that, job failed because your Dataflow staging bucket location is in a different region than your BigQuery dataset, and this may have caused the error.

Another thing, make sure taht you have specified all required [pipeline options](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service). I hope it helps.

Comment: dataflow staging bucket is in the same region as the bigquery dataset which is X.

Comment: Can you specify exactly X and Y?

Comment: Bigquery dataset is in asia-southeast1 but dataflow regional endpoint is not available there. So we use asia-east1 as region and southeast 1 as zone for dataflow

Comment: Storage bucket from which json files are read is in southeast1, as well as staging location and temp location of dataflow are also in southeast1

Comment: You can't specify zone as `asia-southeast1` because it is another region (different than `asia-east1`). Please set up: `--region=asia-southeast1` `--zone=asia-southeast1-a` and let me know about the results. More about region/zones: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones

Comment: That's not possible because dataflow service does not have endpoint to submit job in southeast1 region

Comment: Dataflow regional endpoints are not yet available in all Google Cloud regions. However, you can still run Dataflow jobs in all Google Cloud regions by overriding the zone https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints Have you tried to run it? You can also try with: `--region=asia-east1` `--zone=asia-east1-a` (probably without specifying the `--zone` because it `asia-east1` is the endpoint).